# Objective-C dispatch method with block that will run on the *caller* thread

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, objective-c-blocks

I write a black box class that does heavy processing in the background using Grand Central Dispatch. I intend to provide a continuation style API, something like:

```
- (void) processHeavyStuff:(id) someParam thenDo:(ContinuationBlock)followup;
```

Which a client could call for example like this:

```
[myBlackBox processHeavyStuff:heavyOne thenDo: ^(Dalek* result){
    [self updateDisplayWithNewDalek:result];
}];
```

What's commonly done is that the `processHeavyStuff:thenDo:` implementation calls its continuation block on the main thread using `dispatch_get_main_queue()`. See [Invoke model method with block that will run on the main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944363/invoke-model-method-with-block-that-will-run-on-the-main-thread) for an example.

However this common scenario assumes the client is calling from the main thread. I would like to be more general and call the continuation block on the caller's thread, which may or may not be the main thread. This would allow for example to play nice with Core Data threaded clients where the `NSManagedObjectContext` is thread-local. Is there a good pattern for that?

Using `–[NSObject performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:]`, I can see I could define the ancillary method:

```
- (void) callContinuation:(ContinuationBlockWithNoArgument) followup
{
    followup();
}
```

And then perform that selector on the caller's thread:

```
- (void) processHeavyStuff:(id) someParam thenDo:(ContinuationBlock)followup
{
    NSSthread *callerThread = [NSThread currentThread];

    dispatch_async(self.backgroundQueue, ^ {
        Dalek *newDalek = [self actuallyDoTheHeavyProcessing:someParam];

        [self performSelector:@selector(callContinuation:) onThread:callerThread
            withObject: ^{
                followup(newDalek);
            }
            waitUntilDone:NO];
    });
}
```

I guess that could work, and I am going to try it. But is there something less contrived? Perhaps a version of `performSelector:onThread:` for blocks?

PS: For clarity purposes, I left all memory management calls out of the above snippets. For example, the `followup` block is stack-based and must be copied to the heap to use it on another thread...

Edit: I found out that [Mike Ash](http://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-08-14-practical-blocks.html) uses a very similar approach with:

```
void RunOnThread(NSThread *thread, BOOL wait, BasicBlock block)
{
    [[[block copy] autorelease] performSelector: @selector(my_callBlock) onThread: thread withObject: nil waitUntilDone: wait];
}
```

Where `my_callBlock` is defined in a category on `NSObject`:

```
@implementation NSObject (BlocksAdditions)
- (void)my_callBlock
{
    void (^block)(void) = (id)self;
    block();
}
@end;
```

Answer (score 4):

[dispatch_get_current_queue()](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_get_current_queue) returns the current queue which is the caller queue when called at the beginning of your method. Change your code to:

```
- (void)processHeavyStuff:(id)someParam thenDo:(ContinuationBlock)followup {
    dispatch_queue_t callerQueue = dispatch_get_current_queue();
    dispatch_retain(callerQueue);

    dispatch_async(self.backgroundQueue, ^ {
        Dalek *newDalek = [self actuallyDoTheHeavyProcessing:someParam];

        dispatch_async(callerQueue, ^{
            followUp(dalek);
            dispatch_release(callerQueue);
        });
    });
}
```

One thing I'm not quite sure about is if you need to retain the callerQueue and release it afterwards. I think you don't.

Hope that helps you!

**EDIT**: added retain/release

Comment: I suspect `dispatch_get_current_queue()` doesn't work when the client code is not using GCD. Apple says: "This function is defined to never return NULL. When called outside of the context of a submitted block, this function returns the default concurrent queue". So from a client calling from the main thread, this would return not the main queue, but the default concurrent queue, which would be wrong. Ditto for threaded code that doesn't use GCD.

Comment: @nubbel: Yes, you do need to retain `callerQueue` right after getting it and you do need to release it at the end of the block you're submitting to it asynchronously.

Comment: @Jean-DenisMuys The docs say: "When called from outside of the context of a submitted block, this function returns the main queue if the call is executed from the main thread.". However, your second point is valid.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bad idea to try and guess the caller's intention as to where the completion handler block should be executed. You might guess wrong, and bad things will happen.

The queue returned by `dispatch_get_current_queue()` may be used by the caller in ways you don't expect and cannot anticipate; perhaps they call `dispatch_suspend()` on it by the time you enqueue your completion handler. You also can't assume you can send `performSelector:` to the return value of `[NSThread currentThread]` at some arbitrary point in the future; what if this thread has exited by the time you enqueue the completion handler? What if this thread doesn't have a run loop? In both cases, your completion handler never runs.

It's also contrary to the behaviour of many of Apple's methods/functions that take a completion handler block. Generally, the client supplies a queue directly, or the completion handler is executed on an arbitrary thread, in which case it's the client's responsibility to trampoline over to the correct queue or thread if necessary.

Comment: I just saw your answer after Jody's. I understand you objection. But it would apply to `performSelector:onThread:` too. I think calling the continuation on the caller thread makes sense and respect the principle of least surprise. If the caller wants to do "advanced" stuff as you describe, she can always call my API on the main thread, even from an ancillary thread.

Comment: Finally, calling the continuation on the same thread avoids a context switch (at least theoretically)

Comment: I agree this is a bad idea. You have no reason to expect the thread to still exist or, if it does, that it's cooperating with mechanisms to allow it to run your task. Basically, it would have to be parked in its run loop and if it's going to do that, why do any asynchronous work. Instead, just leave it to the caller, via the passed-in block, to direct the continuation work to wherever desired. Or let the caller pass in a queue to which the continue should be dispatched.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply add another parameter to your `-processHeavyStuff:thenDo:` method specifying the queue you want the block to run on. This approach is much more flexible and is used in `NSNotificationCenter`'s `-addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:` (although it uses `NSOperationQueues`, but the principle is the same). Just don't forget that you should retain and release the queue you're passing in.

Comment: Indeed, but then that puts the burden on the client to understand what a queue is, where to get one, which value to pass in this parameter. It also exposes what, from the client point of view, is an implementation detail. Given the cost of the computations involved, it's impossible to hide the asynchronicity from the client, hence the block-based API which is not worse (and probably better, portability set aside) than any other.

Comment: IMHO, if it is relevant to the caller where the block should be executed, then this implementation detail should be exposed.

Comment: Well, many pieces of code are thread-dependent with Cocoa. Anything that touches a Core Data entity for example. In fact, unless you make sure of the contrary, the safest assumption is that *any* piece of code is thread-dependent with Cocoa. When I get a block from my client, if I execute it on another thread I may induce subtle (or not so subtle) bugs. The principle of least surprise frowns upon that. Additionally, if there is a way for me to isolate my clients from threading subtleties, I can see no reason why I shouldn't do it.

Comment: People calling from the main thread expect being called in the main thread. But people calling from a background thread _presumably know what they are doing_ and would prefer to specify if they want their callback in the main thread or still in a background one. After all, most of the time `-processHeavyStuff:thenDo:` will need to run on the UI anyway to show results... why don't you create two API entries? One with a parameter and one with `dispatch_get_current_queue()`? Many `performSelector:...` methods have such variations.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I handle it.  It's flexible, but not very elegant.

Since the question is still unanswered, maybe you are still looking for an answer?  If not, could you please provide what is working best for you?

```
// Continuation block is executed on an arbitrary thread.
// Caller can change context to specific queue/thread in
// the continuation block if necessary.
- (void) processHeavyStuff:(id) someParam thenDo:(ContinuationBlock)followup;

// Continuation block is executed on the given GCD queue
- (void) processHeavyStuff:(id) someParam thenOnQueue:(dispatch_queue_t)queue do:(ContinuationBlock)followup;

// Continuation block is executed on the given thread
- (void) processHeavyStuff:(id) someParam thenOnThread:(NSThread*)thread do:(ContinuationBlock)followup;

// Continuation block is executed on *this* thread
- (void) processHeavyStuff:(id) someParam thenDoOnThisThread:(ContinuationBlock)followup;

// Continuation block is executed on main thread
- (void) processHeavyStuff:(id) someParam thenDoOnMainThread:(ContinuationBlock)followup;
```

Comment: So you enrich the API and clarify the names. Your `processHeavyStuff:thenDoOnThisThread:` is the equivalent of what I suggested. By opening so many options, you bloat the API significantly, especially as the caller may always choose to redirect her block to any thread or queue. Finally, the two most common use cases are the caller's thread and the main thread. I finally decided to go ahead with the outline I gave, especially as Mike Ash does the same, which to me is a rather strong endorsement. Making the method name more explicit is good idea though. Thanks.