# Why does Xcode 5.1 OpenGLES frame capture cause app to crash?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, opengl-es

I'm trying to debug some hand written OpenGLES 2.0 code on iOS 7. The code runs fine in so far as it doesn't crash, run out of memory or behave erratically on both the simulator and on an actual iPhone device but the graphical output is not what I'm expecting.

I'm using the Capture OpenGLES frame feature in Xcode 5.1 to try to debug the OGL calls but I find that when I click the button to capture a frame the app crashes (in OpenGL rendering code - glDrawArrays() to be exact) with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS, code = 1.

To repeat, the code will run fine with no crashes for arbitrarily long and it is only when I click the button in the debugger to capture the frame that the crash occurs.

Any suggestions as to what I may be doing wrongly that would cause this to happen ?

Comment: Same here, but only if I load textures with a background context.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you are doing, but here is what I was doing that caused normal (although different than expected) rendering, and crash only when attempting to capture the frame:

1. Load texture asynchronously (own code, **not** GLKit, but similar method) in background thread, by using background EAGLContext (same share group as main context). Pass a C block as 'completion handler', that takes the created texture as the only argument, to pass it back to the client when created.
2. On completion, call the block (Note that this is from the texture loading method, so we are still running in the background thread/gl context.)
3. From within the completion block, create a sprite using said texture. The sprite creation involves generating a Vertex Array Object with the vertex/texture coords, shader attribute locations etc. Said code does not call openGL ES functions directly, but instead uses a set of wrapper functions that cache OpenGL ES state on the client (app) side, and only call the actual functions if the values involved do change. Because gl state is cached on the client side, a separate data structure is needed for each gl context, and the caching functions must always know which context they are dealing with.  The VAO generating code was not aware that is was being run on the background context, so the caching was likely corrupted/out of sync.
4. Render said sprite every frame: nothing is drawn. When attempting OpenGL Frame Capture, it crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` at: `glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);`

I do not really need to create the geometry on a background thread, so what I did is force calling the completion block on the main thread (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944363/invoke-model-method-with-block-that-will-run-on-the-main-thread)), so that once the texture was ready all the sprites are created using the main gl context.